# UK visit visa refused twice? How do I reach Embassy?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, proof-provenance-of-funds

I'm a woman working in the UAE and I applied for a visit visa to see my friend in Aberdeen and also for tourism. I had booked my hotels and bought my tickets. I provided employment letter and bank statement with my application. I had mentioned I require almost £4,000 for my 13 day trip. I had provided a bank statement until end of October with closing amount of £4,600 and mentioned that my salary of November and December will be deposited before my travel date which was 24th of December.

But the first time it was refused, mentioning that I had only £3,550 as my closing amount. I went through my bank statement - this amount was for September first!! They had overlooked my saving after first of September. I discussed with many companies and I paid a lawyer for consultation. All came to the point that the officer made an error and overlooked my statement. I thought maybe adding more money to my bank statement would make it better. I asked my father for money and he provided me with £2,600 cash which I deposited it to my account.

In my second application I mentioned this was a gift from my father. I provided an invitation letter from my friend. My November salary was also deposited to my account. So my closing amount was now £8,400. But they refused it again!! They had provided one point only. Mentioning that I have added £2,600 and I didn't provide enough documentation for where I got the money. So because of this they cannot trust my documentation.

I had provided my original employment paper, original bank statement. All they had to do was to call the bank but they didn't. Simply with false accusation they refused my visa. All my documents were originals and I was ready for this trip. I had everything planned and it was supposed to be 13 days only. But I won't apply again. My tickets are reserved for 24th of December and I went through so much stress for this two time for a simple visit visa. I have been looking for a way to reach the Embassy. I know there is no right of appeal for a visit visa application.

But how can someone like me can prove their case?

I can apply for judicial review but by the time I get an answer, it is way past my travel date and my annual leave from my job has already finished. I wanted to know if there is any other way I can try. I have lost hope and I'll be cancelling my tickets and hotels soon. I just wanted to see if there is anything else I can do. The first two images are for the first refusal and the third is for my second refusal.

[image][image][image]

Comment: @pnuts I changed only one thing.. working girl, to woman working in... because of what working girl suggests, at least in the US :-)

Comment: @pnuts The first two images are the front and back side of the first refusal letter.

Comment: @pnuts Thanks for pointing it out. I appologize for the confusion. I edited the post.

Comment: @pnuts She is my university friend and she is living in Aberdeen since September. We have known eachother for over 7 years. They had called her and asked her some questions which she successfully replied. She knows me in personal level and had no problem answering their concern. Also in the invitation letter she had mentioned our plans during my stay there.

Comment: These appear to be very vanilla 'funds parking' and 'insufficient capacity' refusals.  Did you read the corresponding sections in http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab? Did you have questions that were not explained there? Please edit. Minded to mark this as a duplicate.  It's 'funds parking' and 'insufficient capacity'.

Comment: @pnuts The problem is that they don't believe my documentation are true and I'm being honest about my situation. I don't have any other way other than bank statement and employment letter to prove my situation. I also don't have time to re-apply since my flight ticket is 24th of December. It seems from all that I'm getting, all the doors are closed on me.

Comment: @gayot I have read many information provided in multiple websites. I did not have insoficient amount in the bank before the gift I recieved from my father. And my bank account clearly shows the flow of cash in my account and my regular salary. If I wanted to park the funds in my account, I would have done it in case I had less money that I require for my trip. I had also mentioned that it is a gift from my father and a letter from him mentioning the same.

Comment: @NahidM reading lots of information on multiple websites is of no value when the most helpful information is on THIS site. You are not taking the information at hand and at this point you should consider instructing a solicitor to unsnarl the situation.

Comment: Note also that the ECO isn't going to start going off and digging for evidence to support your claims, so complaints like "*All they had to do was to call the bank but they didn't*" are really missing the point.  It is the applicant's job to provide evidence to support their assertions.  That might seem unfair, but when you see how little time the ECO has to assess each application (I forget the details, but I recall seeing elsewhere in this site that it's under ten minutes per application) it makes a bit more sense.

Comment: £4000 is an enormous amount of money to spend on a 13-day holiday in a relatively inexpensive part of the UK (i.e., not London) where you intend to stay with a friend (i.e., no accommodation costs). It's nearly 20% of the median pre-tax income in the UK, so one would expect somebody who was going to spend that much money on a holiday would have a lot of money in their account, and not just slightly more (and certainly not slightly less!) than they claimed they were going to spend on the holiday. It just doesn't add up.

Answer (score 5):

"I thought maybe adding more money to my bank statement would make it better"

**This was your mistake!** The ECO got you on funds parking. Which means, because you were unable to adequately support your claim that the money was indeed a gift from your father, they drew the conclusion that you merely added £2600 in order to deceive them regarding your actual financial status. This is commonly done by people seeking entry to work illegally under the disguise of visiting; after all, the better your financial status, the less likely you are to seek illegal employment abroad.

You should consult a solicitor again, be absolutely truthful in admitting your mistake, and then (with the aid of the solicitor) apply again with solid documentation proving that those £2600 were a gift from your father (a copy of your father's employment contract and bank statements that clearly show the provenance of his funds and his motivation for gifting you).

Comment: The money that I got from my father was cash. In no means I tried to trick them. The amount I needed for my trip was £5000 but before adding the £2600, I already had £5800 in my account. If I had less money than required for my trip then it is understandable that I added the extra money to trick them. Anyway, my flight is on 24th, I don't know how to prove the money was from my father since it was cash. And even if I get the closest day of applications, the result won't come back by 24th of December.That's why I was looking for another way.

Comment: "In no means I tried to trick them". I did not say that, but the ECO obviously believed otherwise. Unfortunately there's no faster way of obtaining an entry clearance.

Comment: I understand that the assumption was from ECO. They made assumptions twice. They clearly made mistake the first time and the second time they didn't even tried calling my bank!! My bank statement clearly mentions I recieve monthly salary. I have wsted so much money and maybe if the first time I had gone for judicial review it would have been better. Anyway, Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @NahidM You can try going for a judicial review simply to clear your name for the future, but if your flight is on the 24th I doubt you'll make it, unfortunately

Comment: Yes well now it is waste of money AND time to go for judicial review. I should have done it the first time but I trusted myself too much. I was wondering,if I do apply for judicial review, and they give me visa but after my flight tickets, can I use the visa laster since it's a 6 months duration? Although my application mentions the traveling dates?

Comment: +1, identifying the root issue and explaining it; identifying the corrective measure.

Comment: @NahidM we are not the tribunal, explanations to us about your circumstances will not help.  And for judicial review, there hasn't been a successful judicial review against entry clearance in over 3 years, forget it and accept this answer as the most valuable.

Comment: Thank you for the "most valuable answer". I can study the rules and documentations from UK website and I wouldn't need help from here if I had found a proper explanation for my situation. I had thought maybe someone can help knowing  the details of my situation, which it seems it's not the case. I am here to seek advise, you don't have to be like a cop.

Comment: @NahidM If there was a surer and faster means of going about this, we would let you know, but UK visa offices are notoriously hard to communicate with, and given the amount of applications they deal with on a daily basis, they're unlikely to feel inclined to waste their time on an individual case such as this (unfortunately). Personally I'm bloody grateful to be totally visa-exempt for the UK